# Installing Ubuntu from a bootable USB, what size to make partitions?

Tags: installation, partitioning

Well, I have to switch over to Ubuntu last night after a disastrous reformatting. And I have some questions.

So I successfully got Ubuntu going from the USB and I selected to also install it onto the HDD. It told me I needed to make a root directory (or something along those lines) to install Ubuntu.

After some search I found I need to make a "/" a "/boot" and a "swapspace" partition. I then read "/boot" is not needed. So I made a 4096MB swapspace (hopefully more than I'll ever need). Then I made a "\" with the reaming space on the 1TB HDD.

Is this right? I feel like the "\" should've been like tops 10GB and then the rest unallocated? I think as it is now I will not be able to save a file because "/" is allocated to everything? 
Or did I do it right and "/" has all free space to work with.?

What are the normal partitions I would want under Ubuntu?

(Sorry got a lot of \ and / mixed up)

Comment: This question has been asked here and elsewhere many times over. Do a search for [recommended partitioning](http://askubuntu.com/search?q=recommended+partitioning) or go with the suggested values.

Comment: Ok so I did screw up then, I need to make a /home for all of my documents and such?

Comment: You'll be fine with just a root partition and the swap space. `/home` (and `/boot` and all the other directories) will be created in the root partition. If you feel you'd like to use some of the 1TB for other purposes, then resize it.

Comment: I mean I did notice that /home was created and /documents. But what is this that if I fill up home I will have issues; "I highly recommend a home partition because then when you run out of space on your home partition, it won't affect your applications and more importantly, core components." But this comment shouldn't matter seeing as I already have a home partition as you said?

Comment: `What are the normal partitions I would want under Ubuntu?` It is Ubuntu so you get to choose whatever rocks your [s]boat][/s] partitions ;) `But what is this that if I fill up home I will have issues` No... if need be you can always symlink to another partition :)

Comment: It's useful to make a /home partition, so you have the possibility of reinstall Ubuntu and keep your personal files intact.

Comment: You don't have a separate `/home` partition now. You have one partition to hold 'em all. Running out of space with 1TB to go ... just sounds very unlikely to me.

Comment: So as it is now if I upgrade Ubuntu to 13.X I will loose everything in Ubuntu? But also, I am fine. Unless I want to upgrade?

Comment: Yes people I have read all the partitioning schemes. Seeing as you didn't read my post to see I have already partitioned and want to know if I should re-do it because of how I did it initially. I just want as yes or no. Not "you're stupid for not reading".

Comment: @user1596244 There is no "one and only" way to partition. If you make a mistake and run out of space you can always add space later. Personally I use a swap partition of 1 Gb on a standard desktop, swap = RAM on a laptop or virtual server. I use a separate /home partiton, size depends on how much user data I have and the size of the hard drive, I figure 5 gb per user, 20 Gb for myself. The root partition needs to be 5 Gb minimum, but you will run out of space fast, so normally I use a 20 Gb minimum for root. You can always change later with gparted  so it does not matter.

Comment: @user1596244 There is no yes or no. No, you don't have to redo the partitioning, you'll be fine. Yes, you can redo the partitioning and you'll be fine. Mu.

Comment: @EricCarvalho, yes, having a separate partition for /home is convenient when doing a reinstall. But `tar czf home.tgz /home` and storing it off-disk isn't a major effort either, when you're reinstalling anyway. (Not to disagree with you, mainly to reassure the OP.)

Comment: As for the closing, many people have noted that partitioning is not the same for everyone. If the question has been answered before, yet each time is unique, how has my question already been answered if I just asked it?